# How to add the first number of every row in a txt file to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a txt file that looks like below:

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 0 1 2

3 4 5 6

How can I add the first number of every row to an array meaning the array should contain: 1 5 9 3 and that is it.

Comment: Please update your question to show us what you have tried so far, and which part you were stuck on. Opening files? Reading lines? Getting part of a line? Storing it as an array?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Target file **"test.txt"** must reside in your project folder.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] result = getArrayFromFile("test.txt");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}

private static int[] getArrayFromFile(String fileName) {
    try(Stream<String> stream = createStreamFromFile(fileName)) {
        return createArray(stream);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new int[0];
}

private static int[] createArray(Stream<String> stream) {
    return stream.filter(line -> line.matches(".*\\d+.*"))
            .map(line -> line.split("\\D")[0])
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .toArray();
}

private static Stream<String> createStreamFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Path.of(fileName));
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[1, 5, 9, 3]
```

Please tell us does this solution satisfy your requirements?

And if you have any questions fill free to ask.

Comment: This may work, but it would fail if the file had numbers with multiple digits. How would you work around that?

Comment: @sorifend can you provide the actual example, I'm not sure what do you mean by saying 'with multiple digits'?

Comment: For example if you had `17 2 3 29` then this part of the code would fail `line.substring(0, 1)`, so it might pay to use a more robust solution by looking for the first index of the space rather than a substring of the first character. Of course this won't matter if the file only has single-digit numbers

Comment: @sorifiend oh, sorry, now I get it. Sure that makes sense, I'll edit my comment in a moment